# mouseEnabled + MOUSE_OVER conflict

Tags: actionscript, mouseevent, label

I'm struggling to make my animation work where a seperate areas of a screen evoke a status to appear/disappear on hover and go elsewhere if clicked however, present if you click it for a split second goes to that label and then returns to the start. Any suggestions?

```
//mouse overs (i've only left 1 instance of each event listener here)
comic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,BubbleHover);
//mouse outs
comic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,BubbleOut);
//mouse down
comic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,BubbleClick);


//
// Take the playhead to where the user hovers. 
//
function BubbleHover(evtObj:MouseEvent) {
    var LabelName:String = evtObj.target.name + "Bubble";
    trace(evtObj.target.name +" bubble appeared"); //state which bubble appears
    //go to the section clicked on...
    gotoAndStop(LabelName);

}
//
// Return to the beginning bubble
//
function BubbleOut(evtObj:Event):void{

    gotoAndStop("lookBubble");
}

//
// Go to the Label Page 
//
function BubbleClick(evtObj:Event){

    var MovieClipPage = evtObj.target.name +"_page";
    if (mouseEnabled) {  
        mouseEnabled=false;
        trace(mouseEnabled); // returns false but then returns to "lookBubble"
    }
    gotoAndStop(MovieClipPage);
    mouseEnabled(true);


}
```

From what I understand is happening, when the playhead goes to the BubbleClick label, the `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT` is occurring. Any ideas how I could circumvent this?

Comment: I've now resolved this problem with: `if(this.currentLabel != "comic_page"){}` inside the `BubbleOut()` function however, it'll only run it once. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately it seems like you have found one of few quirks in actionscript. The issue is that if a movie clip has a mouse out-event and mouse is over that object. It doesnt matter if you set mouseEnabled and mouseChildren to false, that out event will still trigger.

The way to handle this is to either manually check state with some bool (isReallyEnabled) or to remove event listener.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.. and yes it's a long time since I asked this question.  Would you suggest to put a `setTimeout` on the other event listener functions and remove the `MOUSE_OUT`?

Comment: 1) Think you should use ROLL_OVER, ROLL_OUT instead
2) Best solution would probably be:

in BubbleClick-function:
"acceptInput=false"

in BubbleOut-function:
"if(acceptInput) gotoAndStop(...)";

in BubbleOver-function:
"acceptInput=true"